# Summation of variations $\sigma^2$ of several independent random signals

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, standard-deviation

Is it possible to prove that for several independent random signals (variables) their variations $\sigma^2$ are added?

I found it [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch2/6.htm), but without proof.

Comment: You mean for additive noise, right?

Comment: @C.Koca, could be, I'm just wondering why variances are added, but not for example just standard deviations, it is not evident for me.

Comment: If several random variables are added, their variations are added. If they are not additive, than you can't blindly add the variations :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know that $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, it is straightforward from the definition of variation.

\begin{align}
\sigma^2_{X+Y} &=\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X+Y))^2\\
&=\mathbb{E}(X^2)+2\mathbb{E}(XY)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2-2\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2 \\
&=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2+2\mathbb{E}(XY)-2\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)\\
&=\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2
\end{align}

I hope this helps.